# Problem in getting current location of a map in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

As I need the current location of a map I used the code as:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

        [locationManager setDistanceFilter:10];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And I am getting the error in the didFailWithError methos as:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    printf("\nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Inside didFailWithError in locationmanager method XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

And I am getting the error message in my console as follows:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Inside didFailWithError in locationmanager method XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2010-12-06 17:58:12.335 ParkingAreaLocator[6992:207] Error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

And the Wifi is on.

I am not getting the current location in both simulator and device 4.0 sdk.

Can any one please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thank you,
Monish

Comment: Have you try why less accuracy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kCLErrorDomain=0 means `kCLErrorLocationUnknown`

> The location manager was unable to obtain a location value right now.
>
> If the location service is unable to retrieve a location fix right away, it reports a kCLErrorLocationUnknown error and keeps trying. In such a situation, you can simply ignore the error and wait for a new event.

Try with less accuracy

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion.Can you please tell me "Try with less accuracy"  means??

Comment: You use kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters for 10m accuracy. Try kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer or others values (idem for distance filter)

Comment: I tried as u suggested still its generating the error.Can u suggest me with any other ideas?

Comment: You try on the device (not simulator) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot simpler than you're making it. I assume from the title that you've got an MKMapView in your view? If so, you can use it to get the user's location.

In your .h, have this view controller adopt the  protocol.

Then in the .m, do this:

```
void viewDidLoad() 
{
    ...
    myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    ...
}


(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)location
{
    //Do whatever! that MKUserLocation is the location the map view just determined.
}
```